# Unable to use oracle regex to split on a composite Delimiter with pipe

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to split a string which has two composite and nested delimiters:

- Level 1: `~|`
- Level 2: `^|`

The problem is that the regex pattern works on a single delimiter like:
`~` or `|` or it also works on a composite delimiter like `~~` or `^^`, but it doesn't work on the above delimiters.

Target String:

```
*~~36415^^Description^^Version-4~~70450^^Description2^^Version-4~~73110^^Description3^^Version-4~~73140*
```

Regex used:
* `[^(~|)]*`
* `[^(~\|)]*`
* `((?!((~)(\|))).)`
* `(?!(~\|).)`

But it didn't work.
However when I changed my Target String to:

```
36415^^MRI Orbit, Face, Neck W W/O Contrast^^CPT-4~~70450^^MRI Orbit, Face, Neck W W/O Contrast^^CPT-4~~73110^^MRI Orbit, Face, Neck W W/O Contrast^^CPT-4~~73140
```

and use the regex:
* `[^(~~)]*`
* `[^(^^)]*`

it works.

P.S.: I uses https://regex101.com/r/Stbwxt/1 to test this.

```
WITH String_splits AS (
        SELECT TRIM(',' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR('~|36415^|Description^|Version-4~|70450^|Description2^|Version-4~|73110^|Description3^|Version-4~|73140', '[^(~|)]*', 1, LEVEL)) String_splits_1
        , TRIM(',' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR('~|36415^|Description^|Version-4~|70450^|Description2^|Version-4~|73110^|Description3^|Version-4~|73140', '[^(~|)]*', 3, LEVEL)) String_splits_2
        FROM dual
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT('~|36415^|Description^|Version-4~|70450^|Description2^|Version-4~|73110^|Description3^|Version-4~|73140', '[^(~|)]*')
)
SELECT String_splits_1
        , String_splits_2
        FROM String_splits;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those multi character delimiters are a bugger, but you can still make it work by replacing them with single character delimiters.  It's also a bit easier if you do it in stages:

> ```
>     with YourData as (
>       select '~|36415^|Description^|Version#=4~|70450^|Description2^|Version-4~|73110^|Description3^|Version-4~|73140' str from dual
>     ), escape as (
>       select replace(replace(replace(replace(str,'#','&sep1;')
>                                                 ,'=','&sep2;')
>                                                 ,'~|','#')
>                                                 ,'^|','=') str
>         from YourData
>     ), recs as (
>       select replace(regexp_substr(str,'#?([^#]+)',1,level,'',1)
>                                   ,'&sep1;','#') rec
>         from escape connect by level <= regexp_count(str,'#')
>     )
>     select replace(regexp_substr(rec,'[^=]+',1,1),'&sep2;','=') val1
>          , replace(regexp_substr(rec,'[^=]+',1,2),'&sep2;','=') val2
>          , replace(regexp_substr(rec,'[^=]+',1,3),'&sep2;','=') val3
>       from recs;
> ```
>
> ```
> VAL1  | VAL2         | VAL3      
> :---- | :----------- | :---------
> 36415 | Description  | Version#=4
> 70450 | Description2 | Version-4 
> 73110 | Description3 | Version-4 
> 73140 | null         | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1bef140d86d3b369946843b0b89a41c8)*

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the initial input string is; I hope that this *is* then one. Would something like this make sense? The idea is: replace current delimiters with something different (e.g. a semi-colon) and then split the string into rows.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '~|36415^|Description^|Version-4~|70450^|Description2^|Version-4~|73110^|Description3^|Version-4~|73140'
  3     from dual
  4    ),
  5  t_replaced as
  6    (select replace(replace(col, '~|', ';'), '^|', ';') rep
  7     from test
  8    )
  9  select regexp_substr(rep, '[^;]+', 1, level) result
 10  from t_replaced
 11  connect by level <= regexp_count(rep, ';') + 1;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
36415
Description
Version-4
70450
Description2
Version-4
73110
Description3
Version-4
73140


11 rows selected.

SQL>
```